# Циклическая прокрутка шкалы

Tags: android, customview

Не могу разобраться, как можно реализовать циклическую прокрутку шкалы.
Рисую ее в customview:

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
startingPoint = mainPoint;
counter = 0;
for (int i = 1;; i++) {
    if (startingPoint > screenSize) {
        break;
    }

    if(i % 4 == 0) {
        size = scaleHeight / 4;
        counter = counter + 1;
    } else {
        if(i % 2 == 0) {
            size = scaleHeight / 8;
        } else {
            size = scaleHeight / 16;
        }
    }
    canvas.drawLine(startingPoint, endPoint - size, startingPoint, endPoint, rulerPaint);

    if (i % 4 == 0) {
        String c = Integer.toString(counter);
        canvas.drawText(c, startingPoint, endPoint - (size + 20), textPaint);
    }

    startingPoint = startingPoint + pxmm;
}
```

Ограничиваю ее до одиннадцати длинных делений:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но мне нужна бесконечная шкала:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Допустим, можно убрать проверку значения counter в onDraw методе, но как это скажется на производительности? Даже если ставлю его значение 1000, уже заметны "подлагивания" при скроллинге.
Вот мой onScroll:

```
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        mainPoint = mainPoint - distanceX;
        invalidate();
        return true;
}
```

И onMeasure:

```
protected void onMeasure(int w, int h) {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();    ((Activity)getContext()).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        h = metrics.heightPixels / 5;
        w = metrics.widthPixels;

        setMeasuredDimension(w, h);

        scaleHeight = h;
        scaleWidth = w;
        screenSize = w;
        endPoint = h;
        midScreenPoint = w / 2;
        pxmm = screenSize / 28;
    }
```

Каким образом реализуются подобные задачи?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Надо рисовать шкалу от начала экрана до его конца. Т.е. цикл должен быть не по шкале, а по ширине экрана. А в цикле уже вести счетчик по шкале, как только он достигнет 11, обнулять.

Такой подход позволит легко рисовать и шкалу со смещением, просто присваиваете счетчику шкалы это смещение вначале и готово. Скроллинг будет не нужным.

Comment: Убрал из проверки выхода из цикла counter. Теперь рисует шкалу по ширине экрана: screenSize - это она и есть (определили в onMeasure, сам метод добавил в вопрос). Все равно, чем дальше прокручиваю вправо, тем дерганнее скроллинг. Или это норма?

Comment: Не понял вторую часть вашего ответа. Не могли бы поподробнее?

Comment: Вам не нужен скрол стандартными средствами, customview не должен выходить за границы экрана, просто ловите `onTouch`, определяйте куда пользователь прокручивает и отрисовывайте видимую часть шкалы. Стандартный скролл будет тормозить при текущем подходе, с этим вряд-ли что сделаете.

Answer (score 2):

В текущей реализации происходит следующее:

- `mainPoint` инициализируется нулем.
- в `onScroll` `mainPoint` изменяется на значение `-distanceX`, соответсвенно при скролле в положительное направление по оси `X` значение `mainPoint` будет уменьшатся.

То есть в какой-то момент значение `mainPoint` будет предположим `-1000`.
Но при этом значение, возвращаемое из `getScrollX()` будет как раз таки `1000`, поскольку `View` будет проскроллено как раз на это значение.

Метод `onDraw` считает, что координаты `View` следующие: `(l, t, r, b) == (0, 0, getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight())` и цикл в `onDraw` будет отрисовывать линейку от значения `-1000` до `getMeasuredWidth()` каждый раз - из за этого и возникают лаги и подергивания. Чтобы их не было нужно отрисовывать линейку не от `-1000`, а от `0`.

Собственно видимо это и имел в виду Евгений.

Как можно исправить:

В `onDraw` получать значение из `getScrollX()`(либо брать тот же `mainPoint`) и рассчитывать метку линейки в нулевой координате. В моем примере с `1000` и значением `pxmm` предположим `24` получается, что в нулевой координате метки линейки будет `41,6(6)`. Соответственно метка линейки `41` и `41,5` будут за пределом видимости, а значение `42` как раз будет отрисовано со сдвигом `42 * 24 - 1000 = 8` пикселов от левого края экрана.

Единственное что - надо отрисовывать немного не с нуля, а с отрицательного значения, потому что метка может быть за пределами экрана, а сама цифра может частично уже попадать на экран. В принципе, чтобы не особо заморачиваться, можно начинать отрисовывать со значения `41 * 24 - 1000 = -16` пикселов, то есть со сдвигом на одно деление линейки в левую сторону экрана.